# Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have final version of XCode 6 (version 6.0.1). In my project, I have problem when running it.
I got

> "App installation failed - Could not inspect the application package."

If I run project again, it runs ok. Another run, problem again... etc. So every second run ends in this error, right after that application run just fine.
I have no problem in XCode 5.

Comment: Me too. Have you found any solutions?

Comment: had to create a new project at last

Answer (score 0):

If you have moved or copied a folder named `resources` or `resource` into your project, try renaming it. Then perform a `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, And was unable to install the ipa. It always ended with an error "Could not inspect the application package." and some warnings in device console

```
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[356] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options   dictionary when installing an app.
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone mobile_installation_proxy[356] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app with unknown bundleID
.
.
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone installd[44] <Error>: 0x101bcc000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 28: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
Feb 10 17:38:16 iPhone installd[44] <Error>: 0x101bcc000 + [MIInstallable installablesAtURL:packageFormat:userOptions:error:]: Failed  to create bundle for …
```

After spending hours, I got it fixed by adding the "Application requires iPhone environment" in info.plist

```
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
```