# "App installation failed: Could not inspect application package"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When doing a Build & Run from Xcode to my iPhone, Xcode continually gives me this error:

[image]

After it gives me the error, there are no console errors and I can run it again; it's fine and deploys to the device without a problem.

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this. I have tried the solutions in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935228/could-not-inspect-the-application-package), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630828/could-not-inspect-application-package-xcode), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659409/xcode-error-message-could-not-inspect-application-package) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015194/xcode-could-not-inspect-the-application-package).

I've performed a `Clean` & a `Clean Build Folder`. I've removed all the files from the workspace, and re-added them. I have checked the bundle identifier and even tried changing it. I tried re-installing Xcode, deleting the app from the device, restarting my iPhone and re-installing the app.

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 on a MacBook Pro running 10.9.5 with an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.0.2. I am also using CocoaPods version 0.34.1.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here are the logs [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249441/xcode-app-installation-failed-could-not-inspect-application-package?noredirect=1#comment41215006_26249441). The first one is from a normal build that runs fine; the second throws an error:

```
10/8/14 21:56:23.413 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11954a000): ENTRY, options: {
    PackageType = Developer;
    ShadowParentKey = "file:///var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/";
}
10/8/14 21:56:23.416 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11954a000): device os is at least 7.0
10/8/14 21:56:23.416 Xcode[89196]: createShadowPath (thread 0x11954a000): ENTRY bundle: /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:23.416 Xcode[89196]: create_shadow_dir_path (thread 0x11954a000): bundle: /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:23.416 Xcode[89196]: createShadowPath (thread 0x11954a000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:23.416 Xcode[89196]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x11954a000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:23.458 Xcode[89196]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x11954a000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/InstalledAppInfo
10/8/14 21:56:23.459 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11954a000): no old package to delta against, falling back to old skool install
10/8/14 21:56:23.460 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11954a000): Blasting the bundle over to the device in an old skool way
10/8/14 21:56:25.321 Xcode[89196]: _AMDeviceUpdateOldPackage (thread 0x11954a000): copy_new_to_shadow: TRUE
10/8/14 21:56:25.367 Xcode[89196]: _AMDeviceUpdateOldPackage (thread 0x11954a000): copying:
/Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
to
/var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe
10/8/14 21:56:25.403 Xcode[89196]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x11954a000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/InstalledAppInfo
10/8/14 21:56:25.406 Xcode[89196]: writeDictToFile:1258 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:25.407 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x11954a000): returning 0x00000000
10/8/14 21:56:27.366 tccd[328]: Unable to verify code signing identity of com.apple.dt.Xcode:  code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
```

When Xcode throws an error:

```
10/8/14 21:56:58.065 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): ENTRY, options: {
    PackageType = Developer;
    ShadowParentKey = "file:///var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/";
}
10/8/14 21:56:58.069 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): device os is at least 7.0
10/8/14 21:56:58.069 Xcode[89196]: createShadowPath (thread 0x112e35000): ENTRY bundle: /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:58.070 Xcode[89196]: create_shadow_dir_path (thread 0x112e35000): bundle: /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:58.070 Xcode[89196]: createShadowPath (thread 0x112e35000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:58.070 Xcode[89196]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x112e35000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:58.197 Xcode[89196]: createSiblingInPath (thread 0x112e35000): returning: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/InstalledAppInfo
10/8/14 21:56:58.198 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): calling MDMCreateDeltaDirectoryForDevice with (
    "Info.plist",
    "ResourceRules.plist",
    CodeResources,
    "_CodeSignature/CodeResources"
)
10/8/14 21:56:58.198 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): dst_ipa_container: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc
dst_ipa: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc/LeÃÅ Camera.app_sparse.ipa
10/8/14 21:56:58.198 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): diffing /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
10/8/14 21:56:58.198 Xcode[89196]: MDMCreateDeltaDirectory:1840 calling MDMDirectoryDiff with:
state->old_bundle: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/LeÃÅ Camera.app
state->new_bundle: /Users/matthewdavies/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Le_Camera-bfqfzezscvpmaxdceudixqcuvokd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/LeÃÅ Camera.app
state->dst_bundle: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc/LeÃÅ Camera.app_sparse.ipa/Payload//LeÃÅ Camera.app, binaryDiff flag: FALSE
    dst_ipa: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc/LeÃÅ Camera.app_sparse.ipa
10/8/14 21:56:58.198 Xcode[89196]: createDictFromFile:1303 ==== Successfully read Manifest cache at /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/a5d81d2c36f0db5ba32cf71be1cf7a86/ae8735d27401ee958a0e977fc19469991b1e08fe/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:58.199 Xcode[89196]: __MDMDirectoryDiff_block_invoke29:1414 calling writeDictToFile with: /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc/LeÃÅ Camera.app_sparse.ipa/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:58.199 Xcode[89196]: writeDictToFile:1258 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to /var/folders/4_/c486ynzs79j339w5fkccjkv00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1/Xcode/LeÃÅ Camera.app.KLv2tc/LeÃÅ Camera.app_sparse.ipa/ManifestCache.plist
10/8/14 21:56:58.539 Xcode[89196]: AMDErrorForMobileInstallationCallbackDict (thread 0x10c8ce000): GOT AN ERROR 0xe8000051
10/8/14 21:56:58.549 Xcode[89196]: SZConduit: _MonitorResultDispatchFunction:140 (0x0x10c8ce000): Got error from service: InstallationFailed
10/8/14 21:56:58.549 Xcode[89196]: _AMDeviceTransferAndInstall (thread 0x10a081000): SZConduitSendPathWithPreflight failed: 0xe8000051
10/8/14 21:56:58.549 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): Install failed on device: e8000051, removing shadow directory
10/8/14 21:56:58.556 Xcode[89196]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplicationBundle (thread 0x112e35000): returning 0xe8000051
```

UPDATE: I found the Xcode logs in Window > Devices:

```
Oct 11 15:55:46 Matthews-iPhone installd[43] <Error>: 0x100524000 -[MIBundle _validateWithError:]: 28: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app
Oct 11 15:55:46 Matthews-iPhone installd[43] <Error>: 0x100524000 +[MIInstallable installablesAtURL:packageFormat:userOptions:error:]: Failed to create bundle for file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Le%CC%81%20Camera.app/ : Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app" UserInfo=0x14fd07380 {LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=28, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app}
Oct 11 15:55:46 Matthews-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[192] <Error>: 0x100384000 __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=35 "Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app" UserInfo=0x157614c30 {LegacyErrorString=PackageInspectionFailed, FunctionName=-[MIBundle _validateWithError:], SourceFileLine=28, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app}
Oct 11 15:55:46 Matthews-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[192] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Oct 11 15:55:46 Matthews-iPhone streaming_zip_conduit[192] <Warning>: __dispatch_source_read_socket_block_invoke:203: Failed to install application at file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Le%CC%81%20Camera.app_sparse.ipa/ : Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x157611d20 {Error=PackageInspectionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.uhnTux/extracted/Payload/Lé Camera.app}
Oct 11 15:55:51 Matthews-iPhone locationd[58] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: Go to Xcode->Windows->Devices and then select your device. At the bottom of the device view should be the log for the device. (If not push the arrow button to reveal it.) Then get the log entries that correspond to the error. (If you can't find it, then clear the log, try installing again, then copying the results.) Then paste those log entries into your question.

Comment: I didn't see an log related to the error, so I cleared all the logs, deleted the app & reinstalled. No logs :/

Comment: This is a case where the Xcode dialog is hiding relevant information. Is anything showing in Console.app?

Comment: @ThomasW I looked in Console.app…Is there a trick to finding the logs? I can't find anything recent; only a couple old crash logs, and nothing that looked relevant

Comment: Try clearing or 'Insert Marker' and then try installing the app. If there is a log from Xcode you should see it.

Comment: @ThomasW Okay I posted it

Comment: That error is different from mine. According to this post: http://software.techassistbox.com/cant-deploy-app-to-ios-8-device_9323844.html the solution is to regenerate your certificates.

Comment: @ThomasW Okay…I'm attempting to do that…

Comment: @ThomasW It looks like I can't generate a cert right now :/ Something is down…

Comment: Updated with devices logs. Looks like it is a problem with not being able find the Info.plist file. I changed the name of the app to not include the "é" character, and that seems to fix it…

Comment: Was the name change something that was done recently?

Comment: Fairly recently yes. As far as I can tell, the name change fixed it. I will post later on in the week as I continue to develop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by an "é" character in the name of the app. I changed the name of the app, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

Go to Window->Projects (xcode6.3.2) and look for your project and delete 'Derived Data' for all your projects with the same name.

I had the same problem, and it works for me.

If above doesn't work try following:

1. Prodct => Clean
2. Check for your product name. If there are non-latin characters or space then remove it.
3. If you have moved or copied a folder named resources or resource into your project, try renaming it. Then perform a clean.

Comment: That's a good answer, but in this case, it didn't work for me

Comment: I had to Clean and Build after deleting the 'Derived data' - it worked

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and for me the problem was revealed by the device log I mentioned above. The problem was that I previously had a (pseudo) .framework copied into my application bundle that wasn't necessary and was causing the error. Doing a clean wasn't removing the .framework. Instead going to Windows->Organizer selecting my project and clicking the Delete button for Derived Data fixed the problem.

Comment: I tried that (I deleted the actual folder in Finder). Nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I think, that problem is with wrong copying the files to the project. Because, when i copied the files to the project and in the navigation menu displays a question mark next to file, run of app displays this error. But when i copy the files correctly and displays something other next to copying files, everything works. But when you have some characters of {ě,š,č,ř,ž,ý,á,í,é,ú,ů} in the project name and problem still be, try to rename without these chars and after should be mistake out.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, updating project to recommended settings fixed that.