# xcode 6.1.1 App installation failed Could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.1

I'm install app to iPad 3 (iOS 8.1.1, debug mode, provision profile and certificate is correct).
I get error in xcode "App installation failed. Could not inspect the application package." See screenshots.
[image]

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249441/app-installation-failed-could-not-inspect-application-package

Comment: Problem fixed. I removed unused dependency from ShareKit(CocoaPods):
Evernote-SDK-iOS
Pinterest-iOS
PocketAPI.
i.e. in one of dependencies was error.